# Why is opencv not using all cores after upgrading to Mavericks?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm running a CPU intensive command on Mavericks (Opencv_traincasscade).  Under Mountain Lion the process used to use all 8 cores all the way though.  However after upgrading it drops to 1 core after a short time.

[image]

Could this be app nap? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being able to use multiple-cores or threads is dependent on the process. This is not AppNap or OS X causing the change.

Your process, `opencv_traincascade`, may be resource constrained after a few moments and thus reduced to queuing up tasks as it waits for disk access or another limited resource.

In this case you may need to switch to a different build of OpenCV:

> Note that opencv_traincascade application can use TBB for multi-threading. To use it in multicore mode OpenCV must be built with TBB.

- [Cascade Classifier Training](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)
- [How do I build OpenCV with TBB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994261/how-do-i-build-opencv-with-tbb)

Installing OpenCV with TBB via `brew`:

```
brew install opencv --with-tbb
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, I will definitely give that a go.  However, there are 2 reasons why I think it might not be the case.  Firstly, the CPU did hit 800% for a few mins when it started, which suggested that OpenCV is capable of using all cores.  Secondly I never encountered this problem on Mountain lion (however, I cant be 100% sure if it was the same build).  The `-mode` parameter is related to rotation of feature detection not cores I believe.

Comment: Actually I take that back! You were right :D  I'm going to answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Graham Miln was correct - the OpenCV installation was wrong.

[To verify this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464545/296446):

```
otool -L /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.9.dylib
# Look for libtbb.dylib in the response,
# if missing you need to reinstall with tbb.
```

To fix this (assuming you installed with homebrew):

```
brew uninstall opencv
brew info opencv # This will tell you about other flags you might be interested in.
brew install opencv --with-tbb  # Simples! :)
```

Comment: Rather than being a separate answer, consider appending this to your question.